# Set xdebug.max_nesting_level to higher value

Tags: 8

On my Drupal 8 installation, I am getting this Requirement Problem:

```
Xdebug settings
   xdebug.max_nesting_level is set to 100.
   Set xdebug.max_nesting_level=256 in your PHP configuration as some pages in your Drupal site will not work when this setting is too low.
```

On my server, I tried setting it under `/opt/app-root/etc/php.ini.template` but doesn't work.

Can this be done on the settings.php or .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since xdebug.max_nesting_level is not available/cannot be found in my php.ini file.

What I did is adding this line to .htaccess from Drupal directory and this solves my issue.

```
php_value xdebug.max_nesting_level 256
```